# Does "predicativitness" of class comprehension in $\sf MK$ affects the value of the class of all ordinals?

Tags: set-theory, ordinal-analysis

If we take $\sf MK$ and $\sf PMK$, the latter is just a weakening of the former by restricting the formulas in class comprehension to be relativised to sets which is by the way a mono-sorted version of $\sf NBG$. Does this weakening affect what the class $\sf ON$ of all set von Neumann ordinals is?

> Is it a theorem of both theories that "$\sf ON \geq icc_0$"?

Where $\sf icc_0$ is the first strongly inaccessible cardinal.

The point is that $\sf MK$ is known to be strictly stronger than $\sf NBG$ in consistency strength, and if the above is correct, then this added strength is not reflected on the least value the class of all ordinals can take in that theory? Does that mean that both theories would have the same proof theoretic ordinal?

Comment: If you know that NBG is equiconsistent with ZF, and that ZF does not prove the existence of inaccessible cardinals...

Comment: @AsafKaragila, but NBG proves that ON is an ordinal, it is well founded transitive class of transitive classes, and since $V$ is equinumerous with it, then it is clearly not reachable by powering nor by set unions from below, so it is inaccessible?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I'm speaking here about ON which is a proper class being a cardinal, i.e. the least class ordinal bijective to some class, and so ON is the cardinality of V. So here I don't mean by cardinals being set cardinals. I think the equivalence between NBG and ZF is with regards to the set realm of NBG, but theorems about classes in NBG are something that ZF cannot touch, nor do I think the equiconsistency level has something to do with it.